# Get only future posts based on custom field date field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to receive posts from only future events for a page in Wordpress. I have a date custom fields which lets me set a date in the future for comparison against today's date:

```
        <?php

            $date = new DateTime();

            $posts = get_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'category_name'     => 'event',
                'meta_key'          => 'date',
                'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                'order'             => 'DESC',
                'meta_query'        => array(
                    'key'       => 'date',
                    'value'     => $date->getTimestamp(),
                    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare'   => '>'
                )
        )); ?>
```

This still shows all posts though, can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think you should rather use `'type' => 'DATE'` in your meta query, and compare it to a formatted date value for today.

Answer (score 3):

If your `date` field is an ACF DatePicker field, then you will need something like this. The DatePicker field doesn't store the value as a timestamp, it stores it in `Ymd` format.

```
$upcoming_events = get_posts( array( 
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'asc',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'date',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => date( 'Ymd' ),
        )
    ),
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this useful, this is how I solved:

```
<?php

            $date = new DateTime();
            $today = $date->getTimestamp();

            $posts = get_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'category_name'     => 'event',
                'meta_key'          => 'date',
                'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'date',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     => $today,
                    )
                )
            ));
?>
```